# About multi Flash.ocx versions in one machine

Tags: windows, flash, winapi, ocx

I have a application using Flash.ocx to get the frame picture from SWF file, after updating adobe flash player to the newest, the frame picture is totally wrong.
Is there a way to keep the old Flash.ocx in my running folder and my application will use that instead of the one in the system folder? I tried add the flash.ocx within application manifest file, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use flash wrapper:  [F-IN-BOX](http://www.f-in-box.com/). I didn’t use it, but it has version compatibility feature.